# Forcing a partial update with SSJS?

Tags: xpages

I am having an issue here:

[Extensions Library Dialog Box refresh / caching issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376480/extensions-library-dialog-box-refresh-caching-issue)

With dialog box content not being updated.  I was thinking as a workaround I could call a function to force the update of the dialog box.

I found some code to do it with CSJS but how would I do it with SSJS?

I did try placing:

XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:computedField1}");

in the onFocus event and onShow client event of my dialog box but I get formID is null or not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put a dynamic content control within the dialog box and use ssjs to update the content  using getComponent("dynContentControl").show("key")